# Count the number of times a list is opened/viewed

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was searching for an answer to this question for more than a day, could you please help me to find out the answer?

I have a list where we are updating the data. I want to know if there is any possibility to check the number of times people viewed a particular list or article in SharePoint.

If I am not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

**Site Usage/Analytics**

SharePoint captures certain site metrics, such as the most popular pages and destinations, but it has limited granularity.

Refer to Microsoft's documentation: [Reporting and Usage Analysis Overview (SharePoint 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg266383(v=office.14).aspx)

**Audit Settings**

A more in-depth option would be to enable auditing on your site such that page and document views are captured in the audit logs. You can then generate reports from that audit data.

Here's some more handy documentation from Microsoft: [Configure audit settings for a site collection](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-F5A346D0-EE0F-4412-A5E6-D9B5ABAA1012).